# How to add hyperlink in KQL query result in Azure Application insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

In image there is a tile named "Product total request" having two column. I want to add hyperlink on column number 2 which is "Total" and on the click on the row or cell of the table total API list should be show in KQL editor. Please suggest the solution.
**I have written query in KQL editor and pined to Azure Dashboard.**
thank you.
[image]

Comment: Please suggest the related solution, It'll be very helpful to me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

ADE does not currently support CSS/HTML or Markdown. As a result, text with an embedded hyperlink is not an option. However, as shown in my example screenshot, you can add a new column with the link and select the column in the render link section in Azure Dashboard. This will ensure the link is clickable from the dashboard

[image]

Output

[image]